# Conditional INSERT INTO based on the output of the function

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to INSERT a row based on the output of the custom function. Right now my code looks like this.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO mols (m)
VALUES (mol_from_smiles(%s));"""
cursor.execute(sql, mol_smiles)
```

mol_from_smiles is a function defined in RDKit PostgeSQL cartridge extension if it matters. SQL queries are executed using psycopg2 in Python.
The problem with this code is that the function might return null which would violate not null constraint. Therefore, I need to check for nullness before inserting. What is the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on conflict ignore` or just check in the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO mols (m)
    SELECT v.m
    FROM (VALUES (mol_from_smiles(XXX))) v(m)
    WHERE v.m IS NOT NULL;
```